# delete from insert into statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert records all record in tableA with value3=True into tableB. I then want to delete these records in tableA. I want to do this in one statement and have tried running the following SQL statement

```
DELETE FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  rowID IN (INSERT INTO TableB (Value1, Value2)
        SELECT Value1, Value2 FROM TableA WHERE Value3=TRUE RETURNING rowID)
```

But it does not work. How can I fix this SQL so that it works as planned?

Comment: Why one statement and not one transaction?

Comment: I do not think it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split into two commands?

```
insert into TableB
select * from TableA where value3 = True

delete from TableA
where rowID in (select * from TableA where value3 = True)
```

Comment: The queries should be run in a transaction.